# Fibers of regular function

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a regular function between varieties. When is the fiber of this map reduced and irreducible? Feel free to add whatever hypotheses you like (for example being a variety over $k = \bar k$; irreducible, etc).

Comment: Do you mean when this fiber is reduced and irreducible? Hard to tell in general.